# Can I change the color of the text loaded from ilab=cbind in Forest Plot in metafor?

Tags: r, plot, metafor

Please, find my data `q` below.

I have produced this Forest Plot, and I would like the encircled text to be red instead of black. Can this be done?

[image]

My script

```
q <- escalc(measure="IRR", x1i=x1i, t1i=t1i, x2i=x2i, t2i=t2i, data=q)
q1 <- rma(yi, vi, data=q, slab=paste(study, sep=", "), method = "REML")

## Forest
forest(q1, xlim=c(-27,8), atransf=exp, showweights = FALSE, psize = 1.6, refline=log(1),
       cex=0.5, ylim=c(0.1, 17), font=1, col="white", border="white", order=order(q$order),
       ilab=cbind(q$x1i, q$t1i, q$ir1, q$x2i, q$t2i,q$ir2),
       ilab.xpos=c(-19.3,-17,-15,-12.3,-10,-8),
       rows=c(2:7,11:13),xlab="Rate ratios", mlab="")

# Headlines
text(c(-19,-16.8,-15,-12,-9.8,-8)   ,15.7,font=1, cex=0.5, c("Events\n per total\n", "Person-\nyrs\n", "IR\n", "Events\n per total\n", "Person-\nyrs\n","IR\n"))
text(c(-18.75,-18.75,-18.65)   ,c(13,12,11),font=1, cex=0.54, c("/ 32", "/ 32", " / 23"))
text(c(-18.75,-18.75,-18.75)   ,c(7,6,5),font=1, cex=0.54, c("/ 37", "/ 37", "/ 37"))
text(c(-18.65,-18.65,-18.65)   ,c(4,3,2),font=1, cex=0.54, c(" / 29", " / 29", " / 19"))

text(c(-11.65,-11.65,-11.65)   ,c(13,12,11),font=1, cex=0.54, c("  /23", " /16", " /16"))
text(c(-11.65,-11.65,-11.75)   ,c(7,6,5),font=1, cex=0.54, c(" /29", "/19", "  /25"))
text(c(-11.65,-11.75,-11.75)   ,c(4,3,2),font=1, cex=0.54, c("/19", " / 25", " / 25"))


text(8                       ,15.7,font=1, "Rate ratio [95% CI]", pos=2, cex=0.5)
text(-27                     ,c(14,8),font=2, c("Progression rates","Mortality rates"), pos=4, cex=0.5)
text(-27                     ,c(1,10),font=1, c("\nCohort: 110 patients included","\nCohort: 76 patients included"), pos=4, cex=0.45)
```

My data `q`

```
q <- structure(list(study = structure(c(2L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 
6L, 9L), .Label = c("WHO-I versus Unknown ", "WHO-I versus WHO-II", 
"WHO-I versus WHO-II ", "WHO-I versus WHO-III", "WHO-I versus WHO-III ", 
"WHO-II versus Unknown", "WHO-II versus WHO-III", "WHO-II versus WHO-III ", 
"WHO-III versus Unknown"), class = "factor"), order = 9:1, x1i = c(4L, 
4L, 15L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 15L, 15L, 12L), n1i = c(32L, 32L, 23L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 29L, 29L, 19L), t1i = c(74.7, 74.7, 22.8, 108.1, 108.1, 
108.1, 48.3, 48.3, 27.9), x2i = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 9L, 
12L, 9L, 9L), n2i = c(23L, 16L, 16L, 29L, 19L, 25L, 19L, 25L, 
25L), t2i = c(22.8, 4.4, 4.4, 48.3, 27.9, 79.1, 27.9, 79.1, 79.1
), ir1 = c(5.4, 5.4, 65.7, 8.3, 8.3, 8.3, 31.1, 31.1, 43.1), 
    ir2 = c(65.7, 339.6, 339.6, 31.1, 43.1, 11.4, 43.1, 11.4, 
    11.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the color of what's added via `ilab` isn't possible, but you can always just add the text yourself using `text()` (e.g., on top of the existing text). This will do it:

```
text(-15, rev(c(2:7,11:13)), q$ir1, col="red", font=1, cex=0.5)
text( -8, rev(c(2:7,11:13)), q$ir2, col="red", font=1, cex=0.5)
```